# Why is it possible for event.clientY to return 1 pixel less than getBoundingClientRect().top?

Tags: javascript

I have created a div with a width and height of 100px, positioned it absolutely with `top: 2px`, and `getBoundingClientRect().top` returns 2. I have added a mousedown event to this div, but it is possible to position the mouse and click on this div in such a way that `event.clientY` returns 1.

I expected that if `getBoundingClientRect().top` returns 2, `event.clientY` should be greater than or equal to 2, but never less than that value.

Below is the code I used to reproduce the issue:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body style="background: blue;">
    <div id="div" style="background: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: 2px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
        console.log(e.clientY, document.getElementById('div').getBoundingClientRect().top);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you pls attach a codepen to this question?

Comment: @A'dumb'person why should they? You can simply copy the code to codepen or anywhere else. With Codepen, you don't even need to login.

Comment: @A'dumb'person I didn't find a way to add runnable code to my question. I'll try to create an example on codepen and send the link.

Comment: @A'dumb'person [codepen.io/jhonasb/pen/jOXoqzz](https://codepen.io/jhonasb/pen/jOXoqzz) I had to change it to `top: 3px` because it didn't work with `top: 2px`. Maybe this is a browser rounding error?

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you're getting from the code is because of the way mouse events are handled by different browsers and precision of the underlying system.

When you use `event.clientY` inorder to get the Y-coordinate of the mouse event, it will represent the client's Y-coordinate of the mouse pointer in pixels relative to the top of the viewport. This value is known to be little bit less precise due to a number of factors, such as the precision of the hardware, browser's event handling, and the OS (Operating System).

However, when you use `getBoundingClientRect().top`, you will be getting the exact top coordinate of the element relative to the top of the viewport, which is calculated based on the layout of the DOM elements.

Now, in your case, you have a `div` with a `top` property of 2 pixels. When you use `getBoundingClientRect().top` it correctly returns 2. However due to the factors I mentioned before, the value of `event.clientY` is sometimes off by 1 pixel. The 1 pixel difference is well within the expected behaviour of the browser and is not necessarily a bug.

Hope I have fully answered your question?